# Web service php

Tags: php, json

tengo este web service POST que trae datos json como hago para mostrarlo en una lista ordenada?

```
class CurlRequest
    {
        public function sendPost()
        {
            //datos a enviar
            $data = array("a" => "a");
            //url contra la que atacamos
            $ch = curl_init("URL");
            //a true, obtendremos una respuesta de la url, en otro caso, 
            //true si es correcto, false si no lo es
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            //establecemos el verbo http que queremos utilizar para la petición
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
            //enviamos el array data
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
            //obtenemos la respuesta
            $response = curl_exec($ch);
            // Se cierra el recurso CURL y se liberan los recursos del sistema
            curl_close($ch);
            if(!$response) {
                return false;
            }else{
                return $response;
            }
        }}
         $new = new CurlRequest();

    $resultado = $new ->sendPost();
    var_dump($resultado);    

    $data = file_get_contents($resultado);
$products = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($products as $product) {
    print_r($product);
}
```

Comment: Muestra el resultado del `print_r` y explica lo que quieres decir con *lista ordenada*. ¿Ordenada bajo que  criterio, por ejemplo?

Comment: solo quiero mostrar el json que contiene ese servicio
https://api.paguetodo.com/product/report/subscriber_agreement/business/places?type=JSON

Comment: El el `foreach`  debes ir poniendo los nombres de cada clave del array. Supongamos que tiene un clave `nombre` y otra `apellido`:  `foreach ($products as $product) {
    echo $product["nombre]." ".$product["apellido"].PHP_EOL;
}`

Comment: No no sale igual.. Solo quiero q me muestre algo de los dato  que esta en el servicio :c he probado ideas como 

$url = "https://api.paguetodo.com/product/report/subscriber_agreement/business/places?type=JSON";
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $obj = json_decode($json);

    var_dump($obj); 

y aun asi tampoco solo sale NULL :c

Comment: Tienes que consultar la forma en que debe consultarse esa API (en su página de documentación o con el soporte ténico), de nada sirve preguntar por cómo mostrar sus datos si todavía no los estás obteniendo, por eso te pregunté por lo que muestra el `print_r` en mi primer comentario.

Comment: lo que pasa es q lo habia hecho pero en javascript y ahi si me mostraba el json.. pero lo nesesito es en php .. por eso me complico bastante .. y gracia por las explicacion :)

Comment: lo que tengo aparte de la URL es un body de json .. que era lo q colocaba en javascript y traia el json por consola

Comment: ¿Y por qué no usas la misma URL que usabas en Javascript?  ¿Y por qué la necesitas en PHP? Si es sólo para mostrar los datos no necesitas PHP. Es más, si necesitas los datos de la API para algo en el servidor, los puedes traer como hacías por Javascript y luego mandarlos al servidor. Aunque no veo sentido a que no funcione, a no ser que estés ejecutando mal la petición.

Comment: ya listo ya resolvi jejeje ... si lo estaba ejecutando un poco mal ... Mil gracias por la ayuda  :D dtb